# Reshaping tab separated file

Tags: files, csv, text-formatting

I have a file that looks like this:

```
 Time   Flag
 0.65   5.885581e-01
 0.56   5.847484e-01
 0.58   5.278409e-01
 0.57   1.140746e+00
 1.00   0
 0.00   0
 1.00   1
 0.00   0
```

But this is because I forgot to transpose something when it was written. So half of the timings ended up in the flag column and half of the flags ended up in the Time column. It should have been

```
 Time Flag
 0.65   1
 0.59   0
 0.56   0
 0.58   0
 0.58   1
 0.53   1
 0.57   0
 1.14   0
```

So in this small example, the first four rows should become the first column. The last four rows should become the second column. Notice that half of the elements in each column are already correctly formatted (in alternating fashion) in the original file.
What would be the easiest way to reshape and reformat this?

Comment: you mean to keep only the last character/digit from the second column? can you [edit] your question and say what is your first file and your final expected output instead?

Comment: reading your last paragraph of your question, your given output is not what you described as. based on your saying output should have 4lines with the same data not sure how you converted them. please [edit] as I said above again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR > 1 { d[++n] = $1; d[++n] = $2 } END { print "Time", "Flag"; for (i = 1; 2*i <= n; ++i) printf "%.2f%s%d%s", d[i], OFS, d[n/2 + i], ORS }' file
Time Flag
0.65 1
0.59 0
0.56 0
0.58 0
0.58 1
0.53 1
0.57 0
1.14 0
```

The `awk` code reads all the data, row-wise, into consecutive elements in the `d` array (skipping the header).

In the `END` block, the header is printed, then we iterate with `i` from 1 to half the length of our `d` array, printing the value at index `i` (the time value) and at `n/2 + i` (the flag value).  The formatting of the output is done so that the time value is printed as a floating point value with two decimals, and the flag value is printed as an integer.

The `OFS` and `ORS` variables hold the default output field and record separators (a space and a newline by default).  For tab-delimited output, use `awk -v OFS='\t' '{ ... }' file`.

For reference, the `awk` code as a free-standing script:

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

NR > 1 {
    d[++n] = $1
    d[++n] = $2
}

END {
    print "Time", "Flag"

    for (i = 1; 2*i <= n; ++i)
        printf "%.2f%s%d%s", d[i], OFS, d[n/2 + i], ORS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP didn't state that the problem required anything other than dividing the file in half, fixing up each half, and joining back togther, but I was wondering how it might be done without that knowledge.

And I'm really liking **csvkit** and especially **GoCSV** for declarative pipeline processing.

#### Convert/set-up

The first step is to convert the fixed-width example data to CSV.  csvkit lets me specify a column-width schema...

**schema.csv**

```
column,start,length
Time,0,4
Flag,7,13
```

and then convert to CSV:

```bsh
in2csv -s schema.csv input.txt > input.csv
```

#### Separate and transpose

I want to split the input by category: flags and times.  And then for each category make a set of one-line CSVs (for transposing in the next step):

```bsh
gocsv filter -c 2 --regex "^[01]$" input.csv | 
gocsv split --max-rows 1 --filename-base flags
```

and for the complementary timings, use the same pattern with `--exclude`:

```bsh
gocsv filter -c 2 --regex "^[01]$" --exclude input.csv | 
gocsv split --max-rows 1 --filename-base times
```

This produces a set of files like:

```bsh
ls flags-*.csv                                     
flags-1.csv  flags-2.csv  flags-3.csv  flags-4.csv
```

and each looks something like:

**flags-1.csv**

```
Time,Flag
1.00,0
```

or:

**times-4.csv**

```
Time,Flag
0.57,1.140746e+00
```

The `Time,Flag` header isn't really important, but it's important to see that it's there and will affect the structure after the transpose.

For each of those files, iterate: transposing, selecting the second column (because the bogus header becomes the first column), and cap-ping with the appropriate header:

```bsh
for FILE in flags-*; do 
  gocsv transpose $FILE | 
  gocsv select -c 2 | 
  gocsv cap --names Flag \
  > trans_$FILE; 
done

for FILE in times-*; do
  gocsv transpose $FILE |
  gocsv select -c 2 |
  gocsv cap --names Time \
  > trans_$FILE;
done
```

#### Stack into columns

Stack the flags and times into their own columns:

```bsh
gocsv stack trans_flags*  > col_flag.csv

gocsv stack trans_times*  > col_time.csv
```

And then zip together (and I was just going to use **csvlook** for its prettier Markdown table, but it also normalized the numbers!):

```bsh
gocsv zip col_time.csv col_flag.csv > output.csv
csvlook output.csv
```

| Time | Flag |
| --- | --- |
| 0.650… | 1 |
| 0.589… | 0 |
| 0.560… | 0 |
| 0.585… | 0 |
| 0.580… | 1 |
| 0.528… | 1 |
| 0.570… | 0 |
| 1.141… | 0 |

which is cute.

But here's the final step using GoCSV's built-in (and new-to-me) SPRIG templates and the `round` function to clean up floats, integers, and scientific notation.  I add new columns based on the originals, then select only the new/formatted columns:

```bsh
cat output.csv |
gocsv add -n Time -t "{{round .Time 2}}" |
gocsv add -n Flag -t "{{round .Flag 0}}" |
gocsv select -c 3- |
gocsv tsv
```

and we get:

```
Time    Flag
0.65    1
0.59    0
0.56    0
0.58    0
0.58    1
0.53    1
0.57    0
1.14    0
```